# AttributeError: module 'django_filters.widgets' has no attribute 'DateRangeWidget'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install Saleor onto Windows. I have been following instructions as per https://saleor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/installation-windows.html. I have installed all necessary packages using python -m pip install -r requirements.txt. But for some reason, all the packages did not install. I have been running python manage.py migrate, over and over and it does not install everything. I get loads of ModuleNotFound errors and have to manually install them myself by googling their package names for pip.

Now, I am after running into a different issue. I get the error AttributeError: module 'django_filters.widgets' has no attribute 'DateRangeWidget'. I do not know what to try and install.

Comment: What's the version of django_filters package you have installed?

Comment: Hey @Pythonist I updated pip and it worked thanks for the help.